# Algolia search with Firebase Cloud Functions returns null

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am currently writing a multi tenancy app. The app stores data in Firestore/Algolia & I have a cloud function to query the index. This is so that a user can only access data of the tenant they belong to.

The search works fine, but the cloud function keeps on returning null, although the logs shows the search results.

I suspect that the object returned by the Algolia JS client cannot be converted to JSON, hence the httpcallable framework is returning null. Below is a snapshot of the code.

I have tried to stringfy the object using JSON.stringify but no luck. Any ideas?

```
exports.getCustomerSuggestions = functions.region('europe-central2').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  if(!context.auth){
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'unauthenticated',
      'Authentication required.'
    );
  }

  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  functions.logger.info("Processing request from user " + uid + " with data: " + JSON.stringify(data));

  const client = algoliasearch(algoliaAppId, algoliaApiKey);
  const index = client.initIndex(angoliaIndex);

  userData = await getUserData(uid);
  userData = prepForFirestore(userData.data()); // strip object properties
  const searchTerm = data.query;
  
  const filters = 'serviceProviderId:' +  userData.tenantId;

  var result;

  index.search(searchTerm, {
    filters: filters
  }).then(({hits}) => {
    result = hits;
    functions.logger.info("Returning: " + JSON.stringify(result)); //The log shows the search results
  });

  return {status: true, data: result}; // data is returned as null
  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `index.search` is asynchronous your function `returns` before the search finishes. You can try to `await` the `index.search` call so that it will wait till the call finishes and after that return

```js
const result = await index.search(searchTerm, {
    filters: filters
})

return {status: true, data: result.hits}
```